# I want to only show my logo when I scroll >50

Tags: javascript, css

I want to only show my logo when I scroll >50.However, my logo still shows up at the top.I'm using the following code.

```
<nav id="mainNav">
...
...
<a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"> <img src="logo.jpg" "class="logo"></a>
...
</nav>

    <head>
     <script>
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scroll() > 50) {
        $(".logo").show();
    }
    else 
    {
    $(".logo").hide();
    }
  });
     </script>

  </head>
```

Comment: That html is completely invalid. You cannot have "body" content OUTSIDE of the `<body>`, or even in the `<head>`

Comment: try using $(window).scrollTop() to read the scroll value - https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: You should also start your logo element out with `style="display:none"` since the scroll event won't always fire on page load